# Force materials to render on top of others

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

In *Blender Internal* there is **Z Offset** setting for *Z-transparent* materials, which put one object over another on shader level only. But what about *Cycles*, how to do it w/o compositor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender Internal and Cycles use completely different methods of rendering the scene - BI draws each face in turn (after optionally eliminating any ‘backfaces’), using a Z-buffer to determine whether each face should appear infront of whatever has already been painted in that place. It is this Z-buffer that is overridden by the Z Offset.

Cycles, however, traces each ray from the camera to the surface. When it hits a surface, Blender determines what would be contributing to the illumination of that point on the surface. Unless the surface is transparent it will not even consider any faces behind that point - so it is not possible to have a material with a property where it will overlay any material infront.

The *only* way of achieving this in cycles would be via the compositor.